# nunit network drive, failing to load tests

Tags: nunit

We currently carry out development on a mapped drive.  When I write nunit tests against a test assembly it will pick up the assembly, however does not recognise any of the tests.

If I move the solultion etc to a local drive and reference it again then everything works fine.

What I really woiuld like to know is why this is being caused, and how I can carry on using a network drive for development.

Comment: Could you please provide a little more information. Which version of .NET? Which version of NUnit? From where do you execute your tests? Command line? NUnit test runner? Some VS integration?

Comment: The version of .NET matters here.  If you are using anything below 3.5, I think, then .Net doesn't trust assemblies loaded from network drives.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200221032112/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/TimH/archive/2007/08/02/114340.aspx), NUnit apparently does not have appropriate permissions to access the assembly when on a network drive. The suggested fix is to add a post-build event to copy the assembly to a local temp directory and run NUnit off that copied assembly:

> 1. Within VS, open the project properties.
> 2. Go to the Build Events tab and enter the following 'Post-build event command line':
>
>    del /q c:\temp\nunit*.*
>
>    copy "$(TargetDir)*.*" c:\temp\nunit

A potential issue you may have as a result of this change is related to the AppBase as per [Unable to load <mytest> because it is not located under Appbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424798/unable-to-load-mytest-because-it-is-not-located-under-appbase). The answer there is to update the Settings element within the .nunit file to include an app base of C:\Temp\NUnit then update the assembly element's path to remove any leading directory information.